# ZoneAwareError while integrating angular2-onsenui

Tags: node.js, angular, systemjs, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

did

```
npm install angular2-onsenui@latest --save
npm install onsenui@2.2.x --save
npm install process@0.11.9 --save
```

followed by the change in systemjs.config.js to map to angular2-onsenui.umd.js
Here is my full systemjs.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'angular2-onseni': 'npm:angular2-onseni/dist/bundles/angular2-onsenui.umd.js',
      'process': 'npm:process'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Tried [this](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/1494), didn't help.

In package.json installed vesrsions are:

```
"angular2-onsenui": "^1.0.0-rc.6",
"onsenui": "^2.2.0",
"process": "^0.11.9"
```

The error message in browser(chrome)

> "(SystemJS) Module not already loaded loading "@angular/core" as
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js.
>     Error: Module not already loaded loading "@angular/core" as
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js.
>         at Object.c (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-onsenui/dist/bundles/angular2-onsenui.umd.js:148:19) []
>         at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-onsenui/dist/bundles/angular2-onsenui.umd.js:31:30)
>   []
>         at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-onsenui/dist/bundles/angular2-onsenui.umd.js:72:11)
>   []
>         at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-onsenui/dist/bundles/angular2-onsenui.umd.js:31:30)
>   []
>         at c (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-onsenui/dist/bundles/angular2-onsenui.umd.js:51:18)
>   []
>         at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-onsenui/dist/bundles/angular2-onsenui.umd.js:54:10)
>   []
>         at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:11:26) []
>         at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:24:4) []     Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js  Evaluating
>   http://localhost:3000/main.js     Error loading
>   http://localhost:3000/main.js"

Comment: There is typo in your systemjs, change `onseni` to `onsenui`.

Answer (score -1):

adding the following to index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@2.0.0/css/onsenui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@2.0.0/css/onsen-css-components.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@2.0.0/js/onsenui.js"></script>
```

and the following to system.config.js

```
packages: {
  'angular2-onsenui': {
    format: 'cjs'
  }
}
```

solved part of the problem however "https://unpkg.com/onsenui@2.0.0/js/onsenui.js" has brought in new problems open as question here [Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor at DRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42883571/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-constructor-at-dre)