# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor at DRE

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@2.0.0/css/onsenui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@2.0.0/css/onsen-css-components.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@2.0.0/js/onsenui.js"></script>

  <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
  <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('main.js').catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

system.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'angular2-onsenui': 'npm:angular2-onsenui/dist/bundles/angular2-onsenui.umd.js',
      'process': 'npm:process',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no
    // extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-onsenui': {
        format: 'cjs'
      }
    }
  });


})(this);
```

> onsenui.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
>       at DRE (document-register-element.max.js:1368)
>       at document-register-element.max.js:1363
>       at document-register-element.max.js:1366
>       at document-register-element.max.js:1385

This is where it is breaking
https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/7709973bdba5c464de09e5f83c6f83d9253d14b7/core/vendor/document-register-element.max.js#L1407